# How can I use the IMPORTRANGE formula to dynamically perform a DATEVLAUE JOIN on that imported data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with imported date/time that needs to be formated for true date time. I'd like to importrange that data into a different sheet with formatting applied. My initial thought is to use the IMPORTRANGE function along with a DATEVALUE and JOIN. Is this the right approach for this?

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet","Data!A1:A5002")

=DATEVALUE(JOIN("-", RIGHT(A1,4), {MID(A1,5,3), MID(A1,9,2)}))
```

Example data

```
Sun Feb 07 14:22:26 +0000 2021
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that second command is in another column and translates data from column one.
As this column is quite long, it's useful to wrap it with arrayformula:

To make it you have to get rid of `JOIN` formula that does not work with `Arrayformula`
The result is:

```
=ArrayFormula(DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1:A5002,4)&"-"&MID(A1:A5002,5,3)&"-"&MID(A1:A5002,9,2)))
```

You can also convert everything in one column and replace `A1:5002` with `IMPORTRANGE("sheet","Data!A1:A5002")` in all 3 places.

```
=ArrayFormula(DATEVALUE(RIGHT(IMPORTRANGE("sheet","Data!A1:A5002"),4)&"-"&MID(IMPORTRANGE("sheet","Data!A1:A5002"),5,3)&"-"&MID(IMPORTRANGE("sheet","Data!A1:A5002"),9,2)))
```

Warning - this will slow down your sheet a bit as `importrange` is a slow formula.